# XSLT code for Database access SQL server

Tags: xslt, biztalk

is there any possible way to access the SQL server database using custom XSLT code in biztalk mapper,In biztalk we have databaselookup node is available to access and get excat value from DB.

I need a Code to access SQL Database in xsl code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this out by adding the database lookup and value extractor functoid to a map and then clicking Validate Map and then looking at the XSL file generated.

It will look something like the following.

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="ScriptNS0:DBLookup(0 , string(XPATHTOVALUETOLOOKUP/text()) , &quot;CONNECTIONSTRING&quot; , &quot;TABLENAME&quot; , &quot;COLUMNNAME&quot;)" />
<xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="ScriptNS0:DBValueExtract(string($var:v1) , &quot;EXTRACTCOLUMNNAME&quot;)" />
```

This will output the value that was looked up.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var:v2" />
```

There will also be the following just before the end of the template.

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v3" select="ScriptNS0:DBLookupShutdown()" />
```

Notes:

1. The items in all capital will need to be the values for fields, connection string, table and column to return.
2. The variable names v1 to v3 may vary depending on what variables you have already used.
3. If you are looking up reference data another option for looking things up are the Xref functoids which avoid having to have a connection string making for an easier deployment.  See my blog [BizTalk Pattern: Translating Reference Data in a Map using Xref](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/biztalk-pattern-translating-reference-data-in-a-map-using-xref/)

Comment: your right while ignoring the map content of grid..the namespace error ill come.

Comment: we can use internal script function can access database and get exact value what the same thing doing on datalookup functoids. Thanks Dijkgraaf for your response

Comment: for the purpose of moving from mapping functoids to customxslt